Facing "Model Not Found (IpublishedContent)" Issue in Umabrco10 when enable permission "Is Element Type" to true into the Nested Content
I have Migrated the Project from Umbraco 8 to 10 and I have also updated the project version from
Net framework 4.6.1 to NetCore 6.0.
So, when we update the "Document Type" in the Umbraco back office for "Nested Content" and enable the permission "IsElementType" to true then we are getting below given Error :
"One or more compilation references may be missing. If you're seeing this in a published application, set 'CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory' to true in your project file to ensure files in the refs directory are published."
Please check this Video Reference for more information on this issue
Video Ref(text )
So,if anyone have any solutions or Suggestions to tackle the error then please share with me.
Thank you!
We have tried every steps to make it an element type we also tried the code side to get the values. But we are continuously facing the issue like "IpublishedContent not found" and "model does not exist". when we are set up "Document Type" in the Umbra-co back office for "Nested Content" and enable the permission "IsElementType" to true".

Once you've updated the document type into an element type, it is no longer a type of IPublishedContent, but a type of IPublishedElement.
So you have to generate the models builder again, and build the project (this setup depends on your ModelsMode setting).
